# An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.21), and Bundler cannot continue. macOS High Sierra

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error when running bundle in Rails, using macOS High Sierra 10.13.4.

Have tried running:

brew install mysql

sudo gem install mysql2

Which seem to be the recommended route for Mac and that works fine but still getting the same issue.  Any ideas?

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.21), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds
before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

Comment: Was this successful? `brew install mysql`

Comment: You should try this `xcode-select --install`

Comment: I tried that as well. The only thing that seem to work here was to update to gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.2' since this is the version of mysql2 that gets installed when running sudo gem install mysql2.  Would love to understand why this didn't work before though.

Comment: What version of ruby are you using ? It could be issues with `incompatibility` b/w `ruby` and `mysql` gem.

Comment: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17. I've been using the setup on Amazon Cloud9 without any problems, issues raised when cloning project to a local computer.

Comment: The version of `mysql` could be outdated.

Comment: I've updated to a higher version and that seem to be working.

Comment: Glad. You got it working.